# Writing Big XML in sybase and reading it?

Tags: java, xml, sybase

I am inserting a vey big xml in the Sybase column which has type 'text'.

I am writing it using setString in PreparedStatement and reading it using getString.

But when I select it using getString I don't get the complete XML.

What can i do to read/write the complete XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't Sybase provide support for CLOB data type (that would be more suitable for storing large XMLs) ? In the PreparedStatement, you will need to use `setClob()` instead of `setString()`.

Comment: No there is no CLOB data type in Sybase.

Comment: CLOB is A Java/JDBC technique for storing data in a large character column like Sybase text.  You can use a CLOB with Sybase text columns.

Answer (score 0):

Sybase ASE 15 has a bug when writing text columns of more than 8192 bytes: If your string (XML) has an invalid character (that does not conform to your Sybase database's legal character set) after position 8192 then Sybase will only write 8192 characters of your text and tell you that the operation was successful.

Comment: But my XML has no illegal characters. Just that it is little big in size. I also think that the while inserting the complete XML is inserted but while reading, only a part of XML is retrieved.